# What is the difference between AppInsights 'traces' and Log Analytics Workspace 'AppTraces'?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring, ilogger, azure-log-analytics-workspace

We are logging trace data to AppInsights from an Azure Function using `log.LogInformation(someString);`

In AppInsights we are able to query the data in 'traces'.  The AppInsights account was created using a Log Analytics Workspace.  In the Workspace we see what appears to be the same data in 'AppTraces'.  These two tables have similar fields but completely different names, for example **traces.timestamp** versus **AppTraces.TimeGenerated**.

Are these truly the same data?  Is the data mapped or duplicated in AppInsights?  We are hoping to use the Workspace as our centralized source-of-truth and write all of our queries there.

Comment: Yes, all you are getting from both AI & Log Analytics is same. Application Insights it will collect the data for specific applications which you are configured. In Log Analytics Workspace it will collect all the Application Insights data which you configured while creating the Application Insights.

Comment: Is the data stored in only one location (Log Analytics Workspace) and then mapped to different tables in AppInsights logs?  Is the data stored in both locations in different tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This is the same AI data mapped to the new Log Analytics workspace: **Tables**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/convert-classic-resource#table-structure

**traces <=> AppTraces columns**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/convert-classic-resource#apptraces